# Best way to manage redirects

Tags: php, redirect, meta, drupal-8

I need to have a temporary redirect setup and I just want to know the best way to go. I've looked into .htaccess, php, meta and contributed Drupal modules (this is with a Drupal 8 site) and I don't know which is the way to go.

It is a little complicated and yes I know, not ideal but I need this setup for the next 3 months while I build my new website. I'm just not ready for that to switch over just yet.

This is what I need to do:

`www.myNewDomain.com -> www.myOldDomain.com`

`www.myNewDomain.com/sub1 -> www.myNewDomain.com/sub1`

`www.myNewDomain.com/sub2 -> www.myNewDomain.com/sub2`

In other words, anything to the main domain only (no sub directory) gets bumped back to the old site URL.

But my subpages (micro-sites) go through as normal on the new site.

This is what I have so far using .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myNewDomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://myOldDomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Any advise is very much appreciated.

Comment: i would use .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You don't actually need `mod_rewrite` to do this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite)

You want a simple redirect just for a URI of `/` with nothing following it; everything else isn't redirected.

Try this (I haven't):

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://myOldDomain.com/
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That's so much better than what I had.